# How to view the page source for angular 2 app

Tags: angular, seo, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have web app, whenever i am view the page source using browser view page source i am only able to see the index.html contents in page source where as i am able to see the all the html code in inspect element but not in page source. Does any one how to view the page source ??

Below is the server.ts

[image]

Comment: Browser developer tools -> DOM ?

Comment: go to sources section in dev tools

Comment: Sources section where ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only possible with [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/) (server side rendering). Every *javascript* files renders in browser, to see page source you have to setup `Angular 2` to render on server side. It's also useful for SEO optimization.

On [this](https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/) site you have guide how to setup it.

For `Angular 5` you have to visit this [page](https://angular.io/guide/universal), for more informations.

For example working on `NodeJS` visit this [page](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)

Comment: Okay great. Thanks @Patryk but can also refer any link of example??

Comment: Thanks for the help. Need to understand first bit complicated

Comment: Just `git clone` repo from above and read this https://scotch.io/tutorials/server-side-rendering-in-angular-2-with-angular-universal article. I think it will be easy to understand with it. Gr.

Comment: hey @Patryk i followed link but getting error at import { readFileSync } from 'fs'; also process.env.PORT || 4000 cannot find module process and join(__dirname,'..','dist') cannot find module __dirname. Do you have any idea how to resolve this

Comment: Could you show me whole server.ts ?

But before try to import it at top of server.ts  `import { join } from 'path';`

Comment: Updated please check

Comment: Is it because I am using cli version 5.2.2 ?

Comment: Import AppServerModuleFactory like that :
`const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');`  ('./dist/server/main.bundle/ is a path to your server main bundle)

and delete line with readFileSync and with `renderModuleFactory`

+ Make sure that you installed all express and universal packages.

Comment: But  i only want to achieve seo for the pages and dont want to dive deeply in the server side rendering as it has lot vast concept. Even though I will do the necessary changes... anf let u know

Comment: I'm just writting what is necessary only ;) Make changes, and type `npm install --save @angular/platform-server @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader ts-loader @nguniversal/express-engine` in console again. Then try to compile whole build.

Comment: Hey @Patryk i have achieved server.js and now when i execute server.js i am facing this error fs.js:641
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode); do you have any idea about this ??

Comment: Make it in .angular-cli.json "apps"> "scripts" section. Load every JS file there.

Comment: Okay I have loaded all the files there only except jquery do i need to load that too ?

Comment: Yes, you should load it there too. Insert it before all scripts which require jQuery.

Comment: Okay done building it up all again. Let me check once ready let you know

Comment: no not yet still the same error. @Patryk please check server.js file updated here

Comment: Hey @Patryk I am having 3rd party libraries that are using the object navigator for the window how to avoid it in the universal. I have managed everything now only error i am facing while running server.js gives this error of navigator is not found and  Invalid regular expression:

Comment: If Universal is working, (you can see View Page Source) make another topic and describe your problem. Gr.

Comment: No its not working at all my server.js is throwing errors

Comment: Try to copy server.ts from that repo if you are using Angular 5.X https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/server.ts , or step by step follow official guide from there https://angular.io/guide/universal

`const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');` is your dist path`

`const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');` is your main server bundle path

Comment: Do you have any idea to load Materialize server side ?? resolved window and navigator errors

Comment: https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize/issues/140 read this.

Comment: Ya i have already gone through that but if thats the case than how to achieve SEO in my case. I am on the stage of production and only left with SEO before going live and i am facing this issue

Comment: mpunit, where you able to solve the issue? I am stuck on the same thing, please help